# disable and select asp.net mvc Html.RadioButtonFor

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How can i set `selected = true` and disable this radio button

```
<%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m =>m.AddToLevel ,new {id = "rdSameas" }) %>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The second parameter is the value: `true` for selected:

```
<%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.AddToLevel, true, new { id = "rdSameas", disabled = "disabled"}) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= Html.RadioButtonFor(m =>m.AddToLevel ,new {id = "rdSameas", checked = "checked",  disabled = "disabled" }) %>
```